# Finding an Uber we'll fit in

Tags: luggage, family, uber, ride-sharing

We just booked an airport shuttle from hotel to LAX, for our family of 6 and all our luggage.

We could have got an Uber that seats 6 for about 30% less, but as far as I can tell there is no way in the Uber app to know how much luggage they can take. I don't Uber often, so didn't want to get stuck with charges/fees if we had to cancel, or be late because we needed a second car for our luggage.

How can I book an Uber large enough for my family and all our luggage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Uber offers guaranteed seats but no guarantees about luggage space in addition.  If you want to be sure you can fit in 6 people plus reasonable luggage, you should order the next size up, which is the "[Uber Max](https://www.uber.com/en-AU/blog/learn-more-about-uber-max-trips/)" minivan for 7+ people.  However, this is not available in all locations.

The other option is to book an XL, call the driver immediately, and check if they can fit you & your luggage.  Most drivers are quite good at luggage Tetris, although even they can only do so much to bend the laws of physics; if they decline, you'll need to eat the cancellation fee, but it's usually only $5 or so or even waived if you cancel quickly enough.

Comment: Uber Max didn't show as an option, the largest offered was Uber XL, but it probably would have been perfect had it been available